# Read through loop and find PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:-

```
([0] =>Array([amount] => 1, [address]=> 'a'),
 [1] =>Array([amount] => 12, [address]=> 'b'),
 [2] =>Array([amount] => -1, [address]=> 'a'),
 [3] =>Array([amount] => 3, [address]=> 'a'))
```

How do I make an Loop so that at last I get amounts of a and only positive ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your array is this,

```
$array = array(
    array('amount' => 3, 'address' => 'a'),
    array('amount' => 26, 'address' => 'a'),
    array('amount' => 345, 'address' => 'a'),
    array('amount' => -3, 'address' => 'a'),
    array('amount' => 22, 'address' => 'a'),    
);
```

You can write a small `for` loop to achieve this,

```
$results = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v){   
    if($v['amount'] > 0 && $v['address'] == 'a'){           
        $results[] = $v;
    }   
}

print_r($results);
```

This will give you elements where `amount` is greater than 0 and `address` is `a`. Is this what you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Could you be more precise with what you want ?

Assuming that your array is in an var called $_var

```
foreach($_var as $_array){
  if($_array['amount'] > 0 && $_array['address']=='a'){ //if the amount is positiv and address = 'a'
    $res[] = $_array; //Push the current item in your res array
  }
}

$amount_of_a = count($res); //The number of a
print_r($res); //your result
```